# How to enable multitouch for a trackpad?

Tags: multi-touch, eeepc, productivity

I have eeepc 1005ha, and want to have the ability to enlarge and scroll down/up/left/right with the pad, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure the eee's touchpad is a Synaptics type and not compatible with multitouch.

Comment: The new Eee PC netbooks do indeed use a Synaptics touchpad but they *are* multitouch capable.  The drivers in Windows support pinch to zoom and two-finger scroll and middle-click.  I would like to see some info on how to get this working in Ubuntu